# Загрузка файла без использования сторонних библиотек

Tags: php, файлы

Получил тестовое задание, которое звучит так:

> Сделать загрузку файлов на сервер без перезагрузки страницы и без использования сторонних готовых платформ и библиотек. типа jQuery и т.п. 
>   После загрузки выводить ссылки на файлы и при клике на ссылку открывать файл.

Смущает фраза

> без использования сторонних готовых платформ и библиотек

В общем, возможно ли такое средствами **PHP**??
Если да, то направьте, в какую сторону гуглить

Comment: Ну наверное имеется в виду что `jquery` и его оберткой в виде `$.ajax` пользоваться нельзя,а вот чистым `javascript` и `XMLHttpRequest` можно =) Это подсказка

Comment: @АлексейШиманский, спасибо за совет)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Смотреть в сторону FormData:
https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/API/FormData

и XMLHttpRequest:
https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/API/XMLHttpRequest

Вот пример реализации:
http://lesnoy.name/javascript/ajax-%D0%B7%D0%B0%D0%B3%D1%80%D1%83%D0%B7%D0%BA%D0%B0-%D1%84%D0%B0%D0%B9%D0%BB%D0%BE%D0%B2/

Comment: Ответы должны быть развёрнутыми.

Answer (score 1):

Базовый [вариант](http://www.w3schools.com/php/php_file_upload.asp) загрузки файла через html форму и php обработчиком.

Comment: В условии сказано, что процесс загрузки должен проходить без перезагрузки страницы